# -moz-box-sizing rule preventing user from seeing form field input in firefox

Tags: forms, css, firefox

As the title says, I have a weird css error on my hands. I've built a rails app using bootstrap and some custom css, testing the whole thing in chrome initially. I started checking it out in firefox and my user sign in form-fields don't seem to respond to clicking on them or typing. You can't see the placeholder value nor what you're typing. Has anyone heard of this before? Any ideas what causes it?

To illustrate I made a jsfiddle (my first). I was kind of heavy handed and just copied the css right out of my inspector so it's a little bit of a mess. Open it in firefox and the form cannot be typed into. In chrome it's fine. The offending line on this fiddle appears to be 28, the -mox-box-sizing rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/vRF3F/

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.12766%;
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I was confusing Chrome and FF in my answer (now removed). But the box-sizing do work in other context. Must be a combination of something else that triggers it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found the cause:

If you remove this line:

```
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    color: #555555;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
/*    height: 20px;*/
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

it will work. Setting the height property will cause the parent div to collapse so you won't see the input box anymore, hence it appear to not work. The padding alone should be fine to give it a height.

See updated fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/vRF3F/3/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap CSS does include the `box-sizing` property with all vendor prefixes in that selector, I don't know why you are only getting the `-moz`

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    ...
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ...
}
```

Try updating your CSS with that and you will note that your inputs are now smaller in height so just set a specific value for height and I think you'll be good to go

```
.new-user input[type="text"],.new-user input[type="password"]{
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: It's definitely in the bootstrap.css file itself. I just copied the code directly from firebug, which only displays the rules being used. But it appears as you've written it in my css file. Sorry for the confusion. As I commented above, I don't think firefox supports box-sizing anyhow - http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing